# Pandas: Finding sets of rows with some duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of sensor data stored in pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
sensorID  sensorEventTime   sensorVal sensorStatus
12345     2019-01-01 14:05  0.00      PowerOff
23675     2019-01-01 14:08  3.75      EventOn
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      EventOn
86521     2019-01-01 15:02  2.75      EventOn
86521     2019-01-01 15:02  2.75      EventOff
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      EventOff
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      PowerOff
23675     2019-01-01 15:25  5.39      PowerOff
73412     2019-01-01 15:37  2.78      EventOn
...
```

Sometimes the sensors malfunction and you see two rows with the same values except the 'sensorStatus' where it shows 'EventOn' and 'EventOff' pair.
I want to detect every set of matching rows where the values are all the same but the sensorStatus is in matching pairs of on and off.

I tried using duplicates to detect the ones that are matching based on sensorID, sensorEventTime and sensorVal like this:

```
# Variable data is the pandas data frame with the sensor values
duplicatedData = data[data.duplicated(['sensorID', 'sensorEventTime', sensorVal], keep=False)]
```

This returns the duplicated rows like this:

```
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      EventOn
86521     2019-01-01 15:02  2.75      EventOn
86521     2019-01-01 15:02  2.75      EventOff
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      EventOff
12345     2019-01-01 15:01  1.00      PowerOff
```

But is there are way for me to quickly identify the matching pairs based on 'EventOn' and 'EventOff' status? In this case I will have 2 pairs, one for sensor 12345 and one for sensor 86521.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df[df.columns[:-1]].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(by='sensorID')
```

Output:

```
 sensorID   sensorEventTime  sensorVal sensorStatus
2     12345  2019-01-01 15:01       1.00      EventOn
5     12345  2019-01-01 15:01       1.00     EventOff
3     86521  2019-01-01 15:02       2.75      EventOn
4     86521  2019-01-01 15:02       2.75     EventOff
```

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have shown a better sample of the data. Please see updated post, in this case there is entirely possible to have multiple rows besides just event on and off. I think the sorting would probably still work followed by some looping on corresponding matching rows.

Comment: So you only wanted the EventON and EventOFF satuses?

Comment: Yes, if there is a matching EventOn and EventOff, then it is a pair, otherwise it isn't. In case there is an EventOn and a corresponding row with PowerOff, but there is no EventOff, then it is not a match

Answer (score 0):

`data.groupby(['sensorID', 'sensorEventTime', sensorVal]).count().reset_index()`
will give you row counts - ones which are greater than one will be duplicates